# SQL: How do create a new column and its value is referencing another column from another table?

Tags: sql, oracle

Assume there are 2 tables here: `ACCT_PROFILE , CUST_PROFILE`

And the Primary Key is:

**ACCT_PROFILE:**

```
PU_CODE
AC_NBR
CUST_ID
```

**CUST_PROFILE:**

```
PU_CODE
CUST_ID
```

We do not set up any foreign key but the CUST_ID is the same in two table and you can join it base on PU_CODE and CUST_ID.

In CUST_PROFILE, there is a column called MSG_SOURCE

For some reason now I want to have MSG_SOURCE column in ACCT_PROFILE as well, but the value must be the same as CUST_PROFILE, any way to do this?

Comment: Describe table LVBM_ACCT_PROFILE. What is the relationship between this and the other table?

Comment: No relationship at all. and MSG_SOURCE is not part of the key as well...

Comment: let me be more specific, for the MSG_SOURCE I create in ACCT_PROFILE, when there is a new record I want to validate this MSG_SOURCE value is the same in CUST_PROFILE for the same CUST_ID

Comment: Not elegant way to do, but as you have not provided much information and the reason for such a poor design without proper constraints, I think you could use a `BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER`

Comment: Given there is no foreign key, what do you want to happen when there is a discrepancy between the two tables?

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what you trying to achive, isn't It what you need?

```
SELECT a.*, c.MSG_SOURCE 
FROM ACCT_PROFILE a
JOIN CUST_PROFILE c
ON A.CUST_ID = c.CUST_ID
```

Or you need to add `MSG_SOURCE` column without changing It's order?

Comment: basically yes but I need a physical column msg source in table A which is a read-only field and the value is populated from Table C